# Integrate Microsoft PowerApps with ASP.Net based web application

Tags: asp.net, web-application, powerapp, powerapps-portal

I have a client who is looking to integrate Microsoft Power Apps with their ASP.NET based web application for task management.

So my question is that what are the prerequisite for doing it and how to do it?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: @Ganesh Sanap thank you!

Comment: I have searched your requirement and found that you can consume REST API in PowerApps. I thing you need to create APIs for your web application and use it in the powerapp.